# I have 2 components and I want a 3rd component to show animation while waiting for the 2nd one to load images

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
import React from 'react';

const ImageList = ({ image }) => {
  const imgs = image.map(img => (
    <img
      key={img.id}
      src={img.urls.regular}
    />
  ));
  return (
    <div>
      {' '}
      {imgs}
      {' '}
    </div>
  );
};

export default ImageList;
```

Ill like to add another component that will show animation while waiting for this to fetch images.

Comment: Keep a flag `imageLoaded` on the state `false` by default. The loader component will be shown if that `false`. Add `onload` callback to the image and set `imageLoaded` to `true`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need a `Loader` component to show, I suggest you build one yourself, but there are plenty ones available to use, such as [react-loading](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-loading)

To setup that with your component:

- `npm install react-loading`
- Then, replace your component with:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactLoading from 'react-loading';

const ImageList = ({ image, loadingImages }) => {
  if(loadingImages){
    return <ReactLoading type={'spin'} color={'blue'} height={667} width={375} />
  }

  const imgs = image.map(img => (
    <img
      key={img.id}
      src={img.urls.regular}
    />
  ));
  return (
    <div>
      {' '}
      {imgs}
      {' '}
    </div>
  );
};

export default ImageList;
```

- At the parent component, set a default attribute `loadingImages` to `true` at your state, such as:

```
state = {
  loadingImages: true,
}
```

- At the end of the `Fetch` function, where you actually use the response to `setState` the images that you pass to this component, also include this:

```
this.setState({
  images: response.data, //possibly how you do it
  loadingImages: false
})
```

Comment: Done and working but I cant get to space it in the middle no matter what I try

Answer (score 0):

See if that's the pattern that you're looking for...

```js
function getImagesMockAPI() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(()=>resolve(['Image1', 'Image2', 'Image3']),3000);
  });
}

function App() {
  const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(true);
  const [images, setImages] = React.useState(null);
  
  React.useEffect(()=>{
  
  getImagesMockAPI()
  .then((data)=> {
    setImages(data);
    setLoading(false);
  });
  
  },[]);
  
  return(
    loading ? 
      <div>Loading images (I could be a Spinner)...</div>
    : <div>{JSON.stringify(images)}</div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```